# Font family change in Sigil

Tags: css, fonts

I'd like to use Sigil to change font family to embedded ones. I believe I've made everything right in CSS. I imported the "1984" font in Sigil.

I have read this tutorial: http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2011/04/embedding-fonts-in-epub-ipad-iphone-and.html and the sample works fine with ADE 3.0 but if I open it, don't edit the file and save, it wouldn't show the embedded files.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 1984, serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src:url("../Fonts/1984.ttf");
}

.s8{
    color: #000000;
    font-family: "1984.ttf";
    font-size: 125.5000%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.0000em;
    margin-bottom: 0.0000%;
    margin-top: 0.0000%;
    padding-left: 0.0000%;
    padding-right: 0.0000%;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: 0.0000%;
    text-transform: none;
}
```

What could I do?
Thanks!

Comment: How did you add the fonts and the CSS code to the e-book in Sigil?

Comment: I added th file with the "Add file" function, wrote the CSS code to the beginning of the style.

Answer (score 2):

`font-family: "1984.ttf";` looks like it should just be `font-family: 1984;`

Also note that zero values in CSS (i.e. `0.0000%;`)  can simply be replaced with `0`

Comment: Thank you! Changed the font family to 1984 without .ttf, nothing happened. The strangest is that if I open the file and save it without editing anything, it'll lose the embedded fonts.